# Derivation of fourth-order accurate formula for the second derivative in FDM for contact node

Tags: finite-differences

I was looking for a way to derive a fourth-order error formulation of a second-order derivative at the contact surface of two different materials. Say, solving a thermal diffusion equation with varying thermal conductivity and diffusivity. Thanks in advance!